# Probability Density function of Poisson distribution

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

This is an assignment I got for my course on Stochastic Processes:

> Let us consider a random variable X distributed as a Poisson P (λ)
> where λ ∼ [0.5, 1].
>
> *(a) Which are the unconditional mean and variance for variable X?* (**DONE**)
>
> (b) Which is the probability density function of X? (Not need to solve
> the integral)

I managed to do the first part (a) but the second part (b) doesn't make sense to me.

How can X have a probability density function if X is a Poisson and the poisson is discrete?
Am I missing something?
Also, the professor says that there is no need to solve the integral, but how can there be an integral if the Poisson is discrete?

I guess the answer lies in this part:

> λ ∼ [0.5, 1]

But I can't find it.

[This is what I did to solve (a)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO4Ax.jpg)

Comment: @Xi'an I don't know, she didn't add anything to that.

Comment: @Xi'an Could you please explain me how to do that?
For question (a) I simply demonstrated that the mean and variance of a poisson is given by λ.

Comment: I suspect the vague notation "$\lambda\sim[0.5,1]$" might be intended to stipulate that $\lambda$ is a random variable with a uniform distribution on the interval $[0.5,1].$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question (a):** One need call the [Law of Total Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) and [Law of Total Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).

> $$\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X\mid \lambda)])$$
>  where $\mathbb{E}(X\mid \lambda)=\lambda$ and
>  $$\operatorname{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Var}(X\mid \lambda)] + \operatorname{Var}(\mathbb{E}[X\mid \lambda])$$
>  where $\operatorname{Var}(X\mid \lambda)=\lambda$

Question (b): If the integral need not be solved, the marginal density of $X$ can be written as the integral (when $k\in\mathbb{N}$)

> $$p(k)=2\int_{0.5}^1 \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}\,\text{d}\lambda$$

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how to calculate Var(X)=[Var(X∣λ)]+Var([X∣λ]).
I think it is:  Var(X)=[Var(X∣λ)] + Var(λ).
Where the Var(λ) is the variance of an uniform distribution, but I don't understand how to calculate [Var(X∣λ)].

Comment: $\text{var}(X|\lambda)$ is the variance of the Poisson $P(\lambda)$ distribution.